# Can't focus on element after right click using selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver

I tried this code but wasn't able to focus on new tab . After right click it doesn't focus on new tab and doesn't throw any error .

```
public class AM1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver d=new ChromeDriver();

        d.get("https://jira.dematic.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa");

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        WebElement addoftask=d.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Create']"));
        Actions a=new Actions(d);

        //Right click on component
        a.contextClick(addoftask).perform();

        a.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).perform();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid, you can't navigate the context menu by key commands to any element on the page.

From the code it seems you'd like to open the URL of the link in a new window. You could also do this by opening a new window to the URL of the link element.

There are basically two ways: Javascript and a composite action using modifier keys when clicking a link.

**Note, though, that both approaches cannot handle `javascript:` URLs or fragment-only URLs with click event handlers attached to them.**

### Javascript

This uses a Javascript executor context to run [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) with the URL extracted from the link element.

```
// Execute a Javascript snippet
((JavascriptExecutor) d).executeScript("return window.open('"+ addoftask.getAttribute("href") +"', 'newtask');");
// Selenium does not automatically switch to new windows
d.switchTo().window("newtask");
```

More on [`JavascriptExecutor`](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#using-javascript) can be found on SeleniumHQ.

### Composite action

This approach uses an action, pressing the modifier key `CTRL` to make the link open in a new tab. It further uses [`getWindowHandles()`](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#moving-between-windows-and-frames) to get a set of open windows (and tabs) and switches to the second one.

```
// Click with CTRL as modifier for new window.
a.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(addoftask).perform();
// Switch to the second window
d.switchTo().window((String) d.getWindowHandles().toArray()[1]);
```

Comment: Right.I am trying to open link in a new window. I tried your code and it will  open another tab,but seems like i am not passing correct parameter,so it throw error page not found. Can you please  elaborate your answer .I checked attached link but didn't find solution.

Comment: I added a missing `return`statement to the Javascript code and tested it (it might have caused some "parameter" error). I can't confirm "page not found" though. Errors may depend on the Chromedriver version - please specify. I also added another approach to open a link in a new window.

Comment: Thanks! 2nd method works for me. I am able to open link in a new Tab.